# ROLLBACK make data in INSERTED table is removed in AFTER INSERT TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server, trigger, insert, transaction, rollback

I give an example to show my problem. I create a table as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
  id INT
)
```

I create a AFTER INSERT trigger to don't allow to insert id=1 into table "a"

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_a]
ON [dbo].[a] AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @id INT
SELECT @id=id FROM inserted
IF @id=1
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR('1',12,1)
  ROLLBACK;
 END
SELECT * FROM inserted
END
```

Then I insert id=1 into table "a":

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1)
```

I get nothing from INSERTED table.

I realize that when I ROLLBACK then:

- the data in table "a" was ROLLBACK (I know)
- data in INSERTED table is also removed.Why is that?

If I change AFTER INSERT into INSTEAD OF INSERT in trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_a]
ON [dbo].[a] INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @id INT
SELECT @id=id FROM inserted
IF @id=1
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR('1',12,1)
  ROLLBACK
 END

SELECT * FROM inserted
END

INSERT INTO a VALUES(1)
```

Then I get the result:

```
id
1
```

That means data in INSERTED table is not removed though have been ROLLBACK.

Help me explain?

Answer (score 1):

Your row is not being inserted in either case.

For `after insert` trigger rollback is part of the transaction. See this Q&A for details.

[SQL Server - After Insert/ For Insert - Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373168/sql-server-after-insert-for-insert-rollback)

Quote from the above Q&A.

> You're inserting one (or multiple) row into your table. Then - still
>   inside the transaction - the AFTER INSERT trigger runs and checks
>   certain conditions - typically using the Inserted pseudo table
>   available inside the trigger, which contains the rows that have been
>   inserted.
>
> If you call ROLLBACK TRANSACTION in your trigger, then yes - your
>   transaction, with everything it's been doing, is rolled back and it's
>   as if that INSERT never happened - nothing shows up in your database
>   table.

For `instead of trigger` the id value of 1 you are seeing is not from the table. It is from the code within your trigger.  This value of 1 is coming from:

```
SELECT * FROM inserted
```

Run this code and you will not get a record back.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_a]
ON [dbo].[a] INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @id INT
SELECT @id=id FROM inserted
IF @id=1
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR('1',12,1)
  ROLLBACK
 END

SELECT * FROM inserted
END
GO
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1);
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.a;
GO
```

Comment: Yes,that is correct but what I need here is not this. I have no intention of solving this problem,I just want to know why when ROLLBACK in AFTER INSERT trigger then data in INSERTED table is removed.

Comment: Read the answer in the link I provided. I also inserted a section into the answer from the Q&A. It is by design.